# pysnmp - Using variables to set the v3 auth & priv tpyes

Tags: python, pysnmp

I have variables set with the required auth `authProto` and priv `privProto` types that I want to substitute for the `usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol` and `usmAesCfb128Protocol` entries below:

```
config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine, user,
    config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol, authKey,
    config.usmAesCfb128Protocol, privKey
)
```

What is the cleanest way to make use of these variables?

Comment: Can't you directly replace `config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol` with `authProto`? Or am I completely misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, no. If I use `authProto = "config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol"` and call it directly it errors out at line 159 in /pysnmp/entity/config.py which seems to be related to the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems that your problem is a simple typo. If you do `authProto = "config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol"`, it is setting authProto to the *text* `config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol`. You want to set it to the *value*. To do this, just remove the quotes:

`authProto = config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol`.

Then, you can just use it directly when you `addV3User`.

Comment: It was being set in one script and called in another, which meant I had to import some methods to the main script, but yes, it worked. Another mechanism I found that worked was to wrap the variable call in an `eval()` statement, which I am probably inclined to prefer as it allows more flexibility in creating the variable. However I'm not sure if there are downsides to using eval.